# How to change a console application to a windows form application?

Tags: c#, windows, console

I had been developing a console application, until our project needed a fancy UI to go with it, so we decided to change the project type to windows form application. We tried putting the code below in our entry point:

```
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new UI());
```

It kind of works, but the original console window is still there.

I've googled out some useful infos like [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/csharpgeneral/thread/ea8b0fd5-a660-46f9-9dcb-d525cc22dcbd) one, but what all they do is essentially killing the window after it has been created, not tackling the root of the problem. So is there any more elegant way to do this?

Comment: Can't you just copy the code to a new WinForms project? It'll also help in maintaining the old one.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Right click your project in the solution explorer and select properties.
Then, under the "Application" tab change the "Output type" of your project from “Console Application” to “Windows Application.”

Answer (score 1):

The project type needs to be set to `Winexe` (depending on the IDE, also called *Windows application*) instead of `Exe` (depending on the IDE, also called *Console application*) in the project properties.